# Opencart 3 get the product option in Latest Product view

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I am modifying the OpenCart default theme and I want to get the the product options on the latest product view page.

I copied this code from the product view page:

```
{% if options %}
 <hr>
 <h3>{{ text_option }}</h3>

 {% for option in options %}

  {% if option.type == 'select' %}
  <div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <select name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control">
  <option value="">{{ text_select }}</option>
  {% for option_value in option.product_option_value %}
  <option value="{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}">{{ option_value.name }}
  {% if option_value.price %}
  ({{ option_value.price_prefix }}{{ option_value.price }})
   {% endif %} </option>
   {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I copied this code in `catalog/controller/extention/module/latest.php`

```
$data['options'] = array();

    foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) {
        $product_option_value_data = array();

        foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
            if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                    'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                    'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                    'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                    'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                    'price'                   => $price,
                    'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                );
            }
        }

        $data['options'][] = array(
            'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
            'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
            'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
            'name'                 => $option['name'],
            'type'                 => $option['type'],
            'value'                => $option['value'],
            'required'             => $option['required']
        );
    }
```

And i get

```
 Undefined index: product_id in F:\xampp\htdocs\*\catalog\controller\extension\module\latest.php
```

In the `foreach` parameter

```
$this->request->get['product_id'])
```

The above `product_id` is `Undefined`, Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to call the model that fetches the product as it is done in product controller.

Comment: @imox i did that mate thats where the Undefined index problems comes from

Comment: can help you without seeing the code mate

Comment: @imox i edited my post and included the code i copied on the model! If that can help you out!

Comment: try this as url : yoursite/latest.php&product_id=231 (a product id that really exists) and see the result

Comment: @imox The latest products only appears on the front page of the store! Thats where i want to custom add the option with the colors of each product

Comment: Do you want to only show options? Or options must be selectable?

Comment: "i am modifying the Opencart default theme"
I hope you are working on a copy?

Comment: @digicart i only want to show the options, just for the user to see the product colors!

Comment: @paulfeakins i am working on the default theme on localhost, is there a problem that i am not using a copy?

Comment: Yes, you should never modify the default theme itself, you should copy and rename it and work on the copy of the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pages you have to replace

> catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\module\latest.twig

```
<h3>{{ heading_title }}</h3>
<div class="row"> {% for product in products %}
  <div class="product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product-thumb transition">
      <div class="image"><a href="{{ product.href }}"><img src="{{ product.thumb }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" title="{{ product.name }}" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }}</a></h4>
        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
        {% if product.rating %}
        <div class="rating">{% for i in 1..5 %}
          {% if product.rating < i %} <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> {% else %} <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}</div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if product.price %}
        <p class="price"> {% if not product.special %}
          {{ product.price }}
          {% else %} <span class="price-new">{{ product.special }}</span> <span class="price-old">{{ product.price }}</span> {% endif %}
          {% if product.tax %} <span class="price-tax">{{ text_tax }} {{ product.tax }}</span> {% endif %} </p>
        {% endif %} 

        {% if product.options %}
         <hr>
         <h3>{{ text_option }}</h3>

         {% for option in product.options %}

          {% if option.type == 'select' %}
          <div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
          <select name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control">
          <option value="">{{ text_select }}</option>
          {% for option_value in option.product_option_value %}
          <option value="{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}">{{ option_value.name }}
          {% if option_value.price %}
          ({{ option_value.price_prefix }}{{ option_value.price }})
           {% endif %} </option>
           {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}        
        </div>
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_compare }}" onclick="compare.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %} </div>
```

> catalog\controller\extension\module\latest.php

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleLatest extends Controller {
    public function index($setting) {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/latest');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $data['products'] = array();

        $filter_data = array(
            'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'start' => 0,
            'limit' => $setting['limit']
        );

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

        if ($results) {
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                }

                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = $result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $options = array();

                foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($result['product_id']) as $option) {
                    $product_option_value_data = array();

                    foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
                        if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                            if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false), $this->session->data['currency']);
                            } else {
                                $price = false;
                            }

                            $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                                'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                                'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                                'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                                'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                                'price'                   => $price,
                                'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    $options[] = array(
                        'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                        'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                        'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                        'name'                 => $option['name'],
                        'type'                 => $option['type'],
                        'value'                => $option['value'],
                        'required'             => $option['required']
                    );
                }


                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'options'     => $options,
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'rating'      => $rating,
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
                );
            }

            return $this->load->view('extension/module/latest', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: i made the changes you suggested! Now i dont get the Undefined error but still in the latest module on the frontend i cant see anything! And i dont get any error any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I have updated again catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\module\latest.twig file. Please copy and replace again . thanks

Comment: i copied your changes but still there is nothing on the front end!

Comment: As you have changed in .twig file you need to refresh the theme in backend by logged in to admin. Then in dashboard page top right corner there is an setting icon. Click on it, will open a pop up.. You have to click on refresh button there... and then check on front end page.. Thanks

Comment: @Prajant jena the cache etc are all disabled mate! I did try refreshing it but there is no change!

Comment: I have already used this code in my localhost and got the result. Please send your admin authentication details of your site I will check it.

Comment: I have added the result image of latest module please check. Thanks

Comment: I does work after all! Don't know what was causing the issue at first but now everything is fine!  Thanks alot mate you are awesome

Comment: is there a way to do the same for the search results and categories? I mean just to get product option in search results and when user clicks on the category?

Comment: Yes Same code you can add in search and category controller and view pages. Thanks